# sum up cells in matrix according to different hierarchical level

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I am using R to make a heatmap from binary interactions. The matrix looks as following

```
    9   401 562 68  71  569 700
9   0   1   0   0   0   0    1
401 0   0   1   0   0   na   1
562 0   1   0   1   1   0    1 
68  1   1   0   0   0   0    1
71  1   na  0   0   na  0    1
569 1   1   0   1   0   0    0
700 0   0   0    0   0  0    0
```

Also, I have metadata corresponding to my Ids

```
    compart group family  category
9    Ex     Prt   A       Ps
401  Ex     Prt   A       Ps
562  Ex     Prt   B       Rh
68   In     Prt   C       En
71   In     Act   D       Stp
569  In     Act   D       Stp
700  Ex     Act   E       Aqua
```

I would like to sum cells at different level, ex here according to family. The table looks then like

```
  A B C D E
A 1 1 0 0 1
B 1 0 0 na 1
C 2 0 0 0  1
D 3 0 1 0  0
E 0 0 0 0  0
```

And also would like to do it at compart level and so on.

I am looking for solutions that would avoid me to do it manually and go for hours of work.

Comment: For reference on sgibb's edit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: Can you explain what the two-way table with the letters A:E on both marginals is supposed to be? (I'm also having a problem understanding what the first table represents for similar reasons.)

Comment: @BondedDust : for instance, two siblings "9" and "401"  their family name is "A" interact with two other siblings "71" and "569" which have "D" as family name.  sum of intra-family "A "interactions is 1, sum of intra-family "D" interactions is 0 and sum of inter-family interactions "A" -> "D" is 0 where "D" -> "A" is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to flatten or "stretch out" the matrix.   Try the following

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

## Let IDs be the metadata data.frame
DT_ids <- as.data.table(Ids, keep.rownames=TRUE)
# DT_ids[, rn := as.numeric(rn)]
setkey(DT_ids, rn)

## Let M be the interactions matrix
## Reshape the interactions data into a tall data.table
DT_interactions <- M %>% 
            as.data.table(keep.rownames=TRUE) %>% 
            melt(id.vars = "rn", value.name="interaction")
## Clean up the column names
setnames(DT_interactions, c("rn", "variable"),  c("rn.rows", "rn.cols"))

## Add in two copies of the meta data
## one for "rows" of M and one for "cols" of M
DT_interactions[, paste0(names(DT_ids), ".rows") :=  DT_ids[.(rn.rows)]]
DT_interactions[, paste0(names(DT_ids), ".cols") :=  DT_ids[.(rn.cols)]]

## Set the key of DT_interactions
setkey(DT_interactions, rn.rows, rn.cols)

## NOW TO SUM UP
DT_interactions[, sum(interaction), by=c("family.rows", "family.cols")]
```

#### I would wrap that last part in a nice function

```
sumByMeta <- function(..., na.rm=TRUE) {
  byCols_simple <- list(...) %>% unlist
  byCols <- byCols_simple %>%
             lapply(paste0, c(".rows", ".cols")) %>%
             unlist

  L <- length(byCols)
  formula <- paste( byCols[1:(L/2)], byCols[(L/2 + 1) : L]
                   , sep=ifelse(L > 2, " + ", "~"), collapse=" ~ ")

  DT_interactions[, sum(interaction, na.rm=na.rm), by=byCols] %>% 
    dcast.data.table(formula=as.formula(formula), value.var="V1") %>%
    setnames(old=seq_along(byCols_simple), new=byCols_simple) %>% {.}
}

## EG: 

sumByMeta("family")
#      family A B C D E
#   1:      A 1 1 0 0 2
#   2:      B 1 0 1 1 1
#   3:      C 2 0 0 0 1
#   4:      D 3 0 1 0 1 
#   5:      E 0 0 0 0 0

## Try running these
sumByMeta("family")
sumByMeta("group")
sumByMeta("family", "group")
sumByMeta("family", "group", "compart")
sumByMeta("family",          "compart")
```

Comment: sumByMeta("family") gives different result compared to specified by user3037937. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Krome, if you look carefully at the OP's data, it appears their output is incorrect.  for example, 71-700 have an interaction, but D-E (and E-D) show no interaction

Comment: @Krome, may be you should add na.rm=T. 1st solution did work for me.